# VF page to display custom related list

Tags: apex, visualforce, related-list, custom-controller

I have two custom objects: 'MRC Cases' (parent) and 'MRC Case Notes' (child). On the MRC Cases Lightning Record Page I want to display all of the case notes associated with the MRC Case, with the full text of each note visible without clicking through to each note record individually.

If I just drop in a related lists widget on a Lightning Record Page, the standard view truncates long fields and requires a separate click through to each record to view the full notes.

I'm trying to create a VF page that displays the full notes. I was able to create a working page using the standard controller for the Case Notes (child) object, but then realized I can't add that to the MRC Cases record page because it has to use the standard controller for parent object and would need a custom controller or extension to access the related records.

I'm stuck writing the controller. (note: the API names for the two objects are "Grievance__c" (MRC Cases) and "Grievance_Note__c" (MRC Case Notes))

Here's what I have:

MrcCaseList.vfp:

```
<apex:page standardController="Grievance__c" extensions="MrcCaseListController" recordSetVar="notes" sidebar="false" >     
      <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!notes}" var="n">
                <apex:column headerValue="Case Note" value="{!n.Note__c}" style="width: 76%; padding:10px;vertical-align:top;" />            

                <apex:column value="{!n.Contact_Date__c}" style="width: 6%; padding:10px; vertical-align:top;"/> 

                <apex:column value="{!n.Contact_Type__c}" style="width: 6%; padding:10px; vertical-align:top;"/>

                <apex:column value="{!n.CreatedById}" style="width: 6%; padding:10px; vertical-align:top;"/>    
                <apex:column style="width: 6%; padding:10px;vertical-align:top;">
                    <apex:outputLink value="/{!n.id}" target="_blank">
                        {!n.Note_Created_Date_Time__c}
                    </apex:outputLink>
                </apex:column>   
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
  </apex:pageBlock>  

</apex:page>
```

MrcCaseListController.apxc:

```
public with sharing class MrcCaseListController {     

    public List<Grievance_Note__c> notes{get;set;} 
    public Grievance__c mrcCase {get;set;} 

    public MrcCaseListController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) { 

        mrcCase = (Grievance__c)controller.getRecord();      

        List <Grievance__c> mrcCaseList = [SELECT id FROM Grievance__c WHERE id =: mrcCase.id LIMIT 1]; 

        notes = [SELECT id,Note__c,Note_Created_Date_Time__c,Contact_Date__c,Grievance__c,Contact_Type__c,CreatedById,LastModifiedById 
                    FROM Grievance_Note__c 
                    WHERE Grievance__c = :mrcCase.id 
                    ORDER BY Note_Created_Date_Time__c];  

} 

}
```

I'm getting this error from the VF page:

> Unknown constructor 'MrcCaseListController.MrcCaseListController(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller)'

Why do I get this error? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are attempting to use a [StandardListController](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_sosc_about.htm) where in this case not needed. For your controller this should be ok.

```
public with sharing class MrcCaseListController {

    private final Grievance__c mcrCase;

    public MrcCaseListController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.mcrCase = (Grievance__c)stdController.getRecord();
    }

    public List<Grievance_Note__c> getNotes() {
        return [
            SELECT  Id,
                    Note__c,
                    Note_Created_Date_Time__c,
                    Contact_Date__c,
                    Grievance__c,
                    Contact_Type__c,
                    CreatedById,
                    LastModifiedById
            FROM    Grievance_Note__c
            WHERE   Grievance__c = :mrcCase.id
            ORDER   BY Note_Created_Date_Time__c
        ];
    }
}
```

Then for the VisualForce page you can remove the recordSetVar parameter.

```
<apex:page standardController="Grievance__c" extensions="MrcCaseListController" sidebar="false">
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!notes}" var="n">
            <apex:column headerValue="Case Note" value="{!n.Note__c}" style="width: 76%; padding:10px;vertical-align:top;" />
            <apex:column value="{!n.Contact_Date__c}" style="width: 6%; padding:10px; vertical-align:top;" />
            <apex:column value="{!n.Contact_Type__c}" style="width: 6%; padding:10px; vertical-align:top;" />
            <apex:column value="{!n.CreatedById}" style="width: 6%; padding:10px; vertical-align:top;" />
            <apex:column style="width: 6%; padding:10px;vertical-align:top;">
                <apex:outputLink value="/{!n.id}" target="_blank">
                    {!n.Note_Created_Date_Time__c}
                </apex:outputLink>
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly